# How can I use sqlite3 with masm32 on Windows

Tags: assembly, sqlite, masm, masm32

Since I have to write a small library in Assembler that accesses a Sqlite3 Database, I have started a search on how to use the sqlite3.dll. I have found a way to do that in fasm (I have to use masm32 for numerous reasons that do not contribute to solving the problem, it simply is a necessity) via `cinvoke` and referencing the library which is not available as it seems.
What I would basically like to know is whether it is possible for me to do a similar thing in masm or if I have to get the Addresses of every function I need to call individually via `GetProcAddress`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't it?  It is simple, as simple as the following:

```
.486
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
include sqlite3.inc

.data
szSQLDB         db  "MyDB.db3", 0
szRandQuery     db  "SELECT * FROM Quit ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;", 0

.data?
hDBase          dd  ?

.code
START:
    invoke  sqlite3_open, offset szSQLDB, offset hDBase

    call    GetQuitMsg

    invoke  sqlite3_close, hDBase

    invoke  ExitProcess, 0

GetQuitMsg proc
local   ppStmt

    invoke  sqlite3_prepare_v2, hDBase, offset szRandQuery, -1, addr ppStmt, 0
    invoke  sqlite3_step, ppStmt
    invoke  sqlite3_data_count, ppStmt
    .if eax !=0
        invoke  sqlite3_column_text, ppStmt, 0
        invoke  MessageBoxA, 0, eax, 0,0        
    .endif        
    ret
GetQuitMsg endp
end START
```

I use a makefile, and Geany as my editor.  The zip includes the test db, sqlite3.inc, but not the sqlite3.dll just unzip files, plop the sqlite3.dll into project directory and you will be good to go.  I also do not use the MS link, instead I use GoLink as it does not need import libs, but if you have to use the MS Link, I have a SQLite import library around here somewhere.

http://www.gunnerinc.com/files/SQLiteTest.zip

Answer (score 0):

Salam,

It's my example code :)

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

include windows.inc
include advapi32.inc
include comctl32.inc
include kernel32.inc
include shell32.inc
include user32.inc

includelib advapi32.lib
includelib comctl32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib
includelib shell32.lib
includelib user32.lib

.const
    SQLITE_ROW equ 100
.data?
    dwResult dd ?
    hDB dd ?
    sqlite3_close dd ?
    sqlite3_column_text dd ?
    sqlite3_exec dd ?
    sqlite3_open dd ?
    sqlite3_prepare dd ?
    sqlite3_step dd ?
.data
    szSQLite3Lib db "sqlite3.dll", 0h
    szfnSQLite3_close db "sqlite3_close", 0h
    szfnSQLite3_column_text db "sqlite3_column_text", 0h
    szfnSQLite3_exec db "sqlite3_exec", 0h
    szfnSQLite3_open db "sqlite3_open", 0h
    szfnSQLite3_prepare db "sqlite3_prepare", 0h
    szfnSQLite3_step db "sqlite3_step", 0h
    szDBFile db "file.db", 0h
    szSQLStmt1 db "create table DBI (nID integer primary key, szName text)", 0h
    szSQLStmt2 db "insert into DBI (nID, szName) values (1, 'RizonBarns')", 0h
    szSQLStmt3 db "insert into DBI (szName) values ('Rizon & Barns')", 0h
    szSQLStmt4 db "insert into DBI (szName) values ('MASM32')", 0h
    szSQLStmt5 db "select * from DBI", 0h
.code
main:
    push offset szSQLite3Lib
    call LoadLibraryA
    cmp eax, 0h
    je @ERROR
    push offset szfnSQLite3_close
    push eax
    call GetProcAddress
    mov sqlite3_close, eax

    push offset szSQLite3Lib
    call LoadLibraryA
    push offset szfnSQLite3_column_text
    push eax
    call GetProcAddress
    mov sqlite3_column_text, eax

    push offset szSQLite3Lib
    call LoadLibraryA
    push offset szfnSQLite3_exec
    push eax
    call GetProcAddress
    mov sqlite3_exec, eax

    push offset szSQLite3Lib
    call LoadLibraryA
    push offset szfnSQLite3_open
    push eax
    call GetProcAddress
    mov sqlite3_open, eax

    push offset szSQLite3Lib
    call LoadLibraryA
    push offset szfnSQLite3_prepare
    push eax
    call GetProcAddress
    mov sqlite3_prepare, eax

    push offset szSQLite3Lib
    call LoadLibraryA
    push offset szfnSQLite3_step
    push eax
    call GetProcAddress
    mov sqlite3_step, eax

    push 255
    push GPTR
    call GlobalAlloc
    mov hDB, eax

    lea edx, hDB
    push edx
    push offset szDBFile
    call sqlite3_open

    push 0h
    push 0h
    push 0h
    push offset szSQLStmt1
    push hDB
    call sqlite3_exec

    push 0h
    push 0h
    push 0h
    push offset szSQLStmt2
    push hDB
    call sqlite3_exec

    push 0h
    push 0h
    push 0h
    push offset szSQLStmt3
    push hDB
    call sqlite3_exec

    push 0h
    push 0h
    push 0h
    push offset szSQLStmt4
    push hDB
    call sqlite3_exec

    push 0h
    lea eax, dwResult
    push eax
    push offset szSQLStmt5
    call lstrlenA
    push eax
    push offset szSQLStmt5
    push hDB
    call sqlite3_prepare

@@:
    push dwResult
    call sqlite3_step
    cmp eax, SQLITE_ROW
    jne @F
    push 0h
    push dwResult
    call sqlite3_column_text
    mov esi, eax
    push 1h
    push dwResult
    call sqlite3_column_text
    mov edi, eax
    push 0h
    push esi
    push edi
    push 0h
    call MessageBoxA
    jmp @B
@@:
    push hDB
    call sqlite3_close
@ERROR:
    xor eax, eax
    push eax
    call ExitProcess
end main
```

It will create database file with name 'file.db', create table named 'DBI', and insert data as many three rows. After insert data three times, it will show the data with MessageBoxA. nID as caption and szName as text.

Have fun with my code :),

> Please add INCLUDE, LIB, and BIN environment to path of MASM installation.
>
> Example:
>
> INCLUDE = C:\MASM32\include
>
> LIB     = C:\MASM32\lib
>
> BIN     = C:\MASM32\bin
>
> And make sure there are paths above when you type **set** on command prompt.

Wassalam.